# How to override devise to redirect to a different URL other than the root when user login or register?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise and I have a root pointing `home#index`, now I want to override devise when a user register or login to redirect to `project#show` instead of the root(home#index). What method do I put in the overidden devise controller? Also do I have to add anything in the routes.rb?

Thank you in advance!

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  end
```

routes.rb

```
      Parks::Application.routes.draw do
      resources :home, :project
      devise_for :users
      root :to => "home#index"
      end
```

available path

```
       show_project_path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `after_sign_in_path_for` hook is what you're looking for: http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for

As you can see from the docs, you can define a route that will automatically be used (by the original implementation of the hook) or you can override it completely.